# #include <new> giving an error

Tags: c++, linux, include, codelite

A certain file I got handed to me requires:

```
#include <new>
```

I just installed CodeLite and Linux so I might be missing the library or something since it gives me a fatal error:

> usr/include/qt4/qlist.h:58:10 fatal error: 'new' file not found

What to do, what to do? I installed the qt4-dev-tools

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you install a recent `g++` and its `libstdc++` (e.g. `aptitude install g++-4.8 libstdc++-4.8-dev`...)?